# VB if-statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, if-statement

I need help to convert the following Visual Basic statement into a PHP equivalent:

```
If Not IsNumeric(siteid) Then

    dr = GetDataReader("SELECT siteid FROM nwsite WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE mac_address = '" & siteid & "'")

    If Not dr.HasRows Then

      Response.Write(sep & siteid & "=" & siteid)

      sep = ","

    End If

    If Not dr Is Nothing Then

      dr.Close()

    End If

  End If
```

I need help with the If statements more than anything.

Thanks

Comment: that's a fairly basic bit of database handling code; if you're struggling with this, you'd be better off looking for some PHP tutorials that teach basic database handling. Don't try to convert it line-by-line; you'll trip over the differences in the way PHP and VB database libraries work. Rather work out what this block of code does as a whole and try to re-implement it in PHP from scratch.

Comment: the vb code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here for the docs you need  to check](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), also [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/if.php)

Seems like you [also need to learn how to use mySQL in PHP](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/)

The code is relatively easy, in its simplest step- almost line for line from what you have to help you see the transformation to PHP (there are better implementations):

```
$siteid = 1; // where 1 is the value of siteid, PHP vars are prefixed with '$'


// you also could do 
//  if(!isset($siteid){
//  if(!$siteid){

if(!is_numeric($siteid){
  // there is no site ID, so get it from the DB

  // Make a MySQL Connection
  mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

  // Run your query
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT siteid FROM nwsite WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE mac_address = ".$siteid) 
  or die(mysql_error());  

  if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    // rows returned
    //assuming only one row is returned, with your siteid value
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $siteid=$row['siteid'];    
  }else{
    // no rows returned
    // do something
  }

}else{
 // $siteid is already a valid value
}
```

Comment: fixed the spelling of `is_numeric()` for you :)

Answer (score 0):

AN if statement goes something like this:

```
if(someexpression){
    $yourcode = "your things";
}
```

quick mockup of your code:

```
if(!is_numeric($siteid){
   //sql call
  $result = yourdb->query('SELECT');
  if(!$result){
      echo "error";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$this->IsNumeric($siteid))
{
    $dr = $this->GetDataReader("SELECT siteid FROM nwsite WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE mac_address = $siteid");
    if(!$dr->hasRows())
    {
        echo "$sep$siteid = $siteid";
        $sep = " , ";
    }
    if(!is_null($dr))
    {
        $dr->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: hasRows() isn't a PHP function

Comment: I never said it was. I was prosuming the GetDataReader method returns an object with a method called hasRows.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you:

```
if (!is_numeric($siteid)) {
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT siteid FROM nwsite WHERE mac_address = " . mysql_real_escape_string($siteid));
   $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   if (count($rows) == 0) {
     print($sep . $siteid . "=" . $siteid);
     $sep = ',';
   }
}
```